# Alternative of ColorFilter in flutter for decorationImage of container

Tags: image, flutter, dart, background, opacity

Currently I am using ColorFilter for giving opacity to decoration image of container.

For Image.asset or Image.network we can use like:

```
Image.network(
  'url',
  color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 0.5),
  colorBlendMode: BlendMode.modulate
),
```

So is their any such alternative for decorationImage??

Thanks in advance for answer and your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

```
ColorFiltered(
  colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2), BlendMode.dstATop),
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```